# Excel count based on cell color, while colors were very similai

Tags: excel, vba, colors

I used VBA to count the cells numbers based on the cells color,
here are the VBA code:

```
Function CountCcolor(range_data As range, criteria As range) As Long
Dim datax As range
Dim xcolor As Long
xcolor = criteria.Interior.ColorIndex
For Each datax In range_data
If datax.Interior.ColorIndex = xcolor Then
    CountCcolor = CountCcolor + 1
End If
Next datax
End Function
```

and I filled the cells with a seriers color, like the picture show.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmagS.jpg)

the wrong count result between color 1 and color 2, color 3 and color 4 were same; I have another color count data with big difference filled cell color,
and that's were right.

I think the wrong data may caused by similar color, I know the similar color (color 1 to color 6)were different, but it seems the VBA code did not konw.

How can I get right data without manual change the similar cells color?

Thanks in advance.
DUERNA

Comment: Try matching on `Interior.Color` instead of `ColorIndex`

Comment: @Tim Williams, thank you, I changed **xcolor = criteria.Interior.ColorIndex**, to **xcolor = criteria.Interior.Color**, and excel show wrong message.

Comment: What does "wrong message" mean exactly

Comment: @Tim Williams, the message is :Ambiguous name detected:CountCcolor.

Comment: That error means you have two Functions or Sub-routines with the same name on the Module.

Comment: @sktneer, thank you, I search the code from website, and I have no idear what is the functions or sub-routines in my code.  I try to instead all *Interior.ColorIndex* to *Interior.Color*, but it not works, all color count result show 0.

Comment: @ Tim Williams @sktneer   Thank you, I deleted all the unnessary module in my VBA (sktneer), and replace all coloriIndex, and it works, thank you for helping.

Comment: @user8606962 You're welcome! Glad we could help.